# How do I use jQuery validation on other element properties aside from class?

Tags: jquery, validation

what I want to do is to use something like

```
name="validate[required]"
```

basically use it other than on `class` property

thank you.

**EDIT**: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[name="validate[required]"]');
```

In above I used **[jQuery equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**. Where I target all `input`s with `name` attribute equal to `validate[required]`.

For more about different jQuery selectors see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: care to elaborate good sir? I'm fairly new to jquery validation. thanks in advance

Comment: @ReyL I tried to elaborate my code and give you necessary links. I hope this will help you. If you have any issue then comment me

Comment: hmm, I was short on describing my question and comment there sir, sorry. I understand this much regarding jQuery, what I wanted to ask was if I could select it, how can I validate it? (please refer to my link in the question) it only uses the class property.